# Unable to unzip using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to unzip using powershell with below command --

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('E:\test.zip', 'E:\'); }"
```

I get below log

```
'E:\test1.txt' 
already exists."
At line:1 char:53
+ & { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; 
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Ex ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException

===============================
```

I don't see the archive being unzipped.

**Update 1**

E:\test1.txt already exists at the destination. How to change the command to overwrite files.

**Update 2**

The version of powershell available doesn't support `Expand-Archive`

Comment: does E:\test1.txt already exist?

Comment: Yes,  E:\test1.txt exists. I want to overwrite this file during unzipping.

Comment: Thats should be your question....How do i overwrite files with unzipped files....i think you should edit your question

Answer (score 2):

You can't overwrite files with that method.  You need to read [the documentation for `ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(source, destinationDirectoryName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttodirectory(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method creates the directory specified by
>   *destinationDirectoryName*. **If the destination directory already exists, this method does not overwrite it; it throws an IOException
>   exception.** The method also creates subdirectories that reflect the
>   hierarchy in the zip archive. If an error occurs during extraction,
>   the archive remains partially extracted. Each extracted file has the
>   same relative path to the directory specified by
>   *destinationDirectoryName* as its source entry has to the root of the archive.

If you want to use `ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory()` with overwrite, you'll need to extract the files to a temporary folder and then copy/move them to the desired location.

Try something like:

```
do {
    $TempFolder = Join-Path -Path $([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) -ChildPath $([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName());
} while ((Test-Path -Path $TempFolder));

mkdir $TempFolder | Out-Null;

[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('E:\test.zip',$TempFolder);

Get-ChildItem -Path $TempFolder -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination 'E:\' -Force;

rmdir $TempFolder;
```

Note that this code is untested.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I wrote simple commands to unzip in temp folder, copy to destination and delete temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what solved my problem

```
md E:\temp
move E:\test.zip     E:\temp
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('E:\temp\test.zip', 'E:\temp\'); }"
del E:\temp\test.zip
move /Y E:\temp\* E:\
rd E:\temp
```